# EKErrorDomain Code=1 in EventKit in ios5.0

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am getting following error in different places like when I am removing an event or when adding the an event.In that desccriptions it is showing that no calendar has been set but I debugged the event calendar and get the calendar is already set.I am confused.

Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1 "No calendar has been set." UserInfo=0x756a8d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=No calendar has been set.}

Can any one suggest me if are there any chcekpoints or I am doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out, try this when creating a new EKEvent:

```
        [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
```

Answer (score 8):

I know the title of this question references iOS5, but I had an app running on iOS5 and greater. My iOS6 users were running into this issue for different reasons - you need to use the new iOS6 method if available to get access to the event store first.

```
- (void)requestAccessToEntityType:(EKEntityType)entityType completion:(EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler)completion
```

Be sure to check availability of the API first, e.g.

```
EKEventStore* eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
    // >= iOS 6

    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent
                               completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

         // may return on background thread
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if (granted) {
                 // continue
             } else {
                 // display error
             }
         });
     }];
} else {
    // < iOS 6

    // continue
}
```